# n-approximable functions

Tags: computability, approximation

I came across the following definition in [a paper](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Nonapproximability+of+the+normalized+information+distance&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=):

> We can extend the notion of an $n$-c.e. [n-computably enumerable] set to a notion that measures the number of fluctuations of a function as folows: For every $n \geq 1$, call $f : N \rightarrow R$ n-approximable if there is a rational-valued computable approximation $\varphi$ such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \varphi(x, k) = f(x)$ and such that for every $x$, the number of $k$’s such that $\varphi(x,k + 1) − \varphi(x,k) < 0$ is bounded by $n − 1$. That is, $n − 1$ is a bound on the number of fluctuations of the approximation. 
>
> Note that the $1$-approximable functions are precisely the lower semicomputable ($\Sigma_1^0$) ones (zero fluctuations). Also note that a set $A \subseteq \mathbb N$ is $n$-c.e. if and only if the characteristic function of A is n-approximable.

I have two questions.

- Is this a commonly used principle? Google didn't give me any relevant results.
- If I have an $n$-c.e. function $\varphi(x)$, with $\varphi(x,k)$ approximating it. Couldn't I just build a Turing machine $\varphi'(x, k')$ that dovetails the computation of $\varphi(x, k)$ until it sees two consecutive halting machines with $\varphi(x, k+1) < \varphi(x, k)$, stops the dovetailing, and outputs $\varphi(x, k+1+k')$ (ie. it computes $\varphi(\cdot, \cdot)$ but starting from k+1). Then, if $\varphi(x)$ is $n-c.e.$ (and not $n+1$-c.e.), it is also $n-1$-c.e., and by induction it is just approximable.

So the definition doesn't seem to make sense. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a special case of what is called an $f$-c.e. set. A set $A$ is $f$-c.e. iff there is computable function $g$ such that

- $\chi_A(x) = \lim_i g(x,i)$, and
- $\forall x \ |\{s \mid g(x,i) \neq g(x,i+1) \}| \leq f(x)$.

If we consider $f(x)=n$ then we get the definition of $n$-c.e sets.

They don't need to be c.e. because c.e. is not closed under complement. Take two c.e. sets and take their difference. It is a $2$-c.e. set but it does not need to be a c.e. set.

[Barry Cooper](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~pmt6sbc/) and colleges have been interested in these sets and the notion of computability in limit. You may want to check his ["Definability in the Real Universe"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.1416) article from ["Computability In Context: Computation and Logic in the Real World"](http://books.google.ca/books?id=48rfPEiv9eIC&lpg=PA61&ots=Zl1g9L9D2Q).

Comment: As far as I can see this just says that (the characteristic sequences of) n-approximable functions and n-c.e. sets are both subsets of f-c.e. sets. n-c.e. sets are a strict superset of the c.e. sets, so f-c.e. sets are as well. Fine. But that still doesn't mean that the n-c.e. functions above are a strict superset of the c.e. functions... right?

Comment: @Peter, the difference of two c.e. sets is an $n$-c.e. set (for any $n\geq 2$).

Comment: I understand that, and I have no problem with the definition of n-c.e. sets. Just with the extension to n-approximable functions above. I don't (yet) see how your answer solves my objection.

Comment: @Peter, here is a simple example: let $g(x,k)$ be $1$ unless TM with code $x$ halts in $k$ steps. $g$ is a $2$-approximation to the complement of halting problem which is not c.e., your dove-tailing works correctly on those $x$ which halt but not those which do not halt. In other words, you don't have the exact number of changes, you only have an upper-bound on their number, and when you don't see a change your dove-tailing will continue forever without returning any answer.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem now. Thanks for your patience.